# Using strcpy on a dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strcpy

I have got a basic question about the following code:

```
int main() {
    char *sNext1="DABCD";
    char Tmp[]="";
    strcpy(Tmp, sNext1);
    return 0;
}
```

There is a error happened in "strcpy" when I run it. It seems that it doesn't allow me to copy a string into a dynamic array. Does anyone know what causes this error? And how can I fix it?

Comment: You think `Tmp` has enough memory to hold your string?

Comment: @andy please don;t add `thank you` and alike, it was removed for a reson. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate memory to `Tmp` before copying the string to `Tmp`.

`Tmp` is an character array of size 1.

Allocate memory dynamically as shown below. (If you are trying to do dynamic memory allocatio)

```
char *Tmp = malloc(strlen(sNext1) + 1);
```

Then try doing `strcpy()`

Comment: Or use a VLA: `char Tmp[ strlen(sNext1) + 1 ];`

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is with

```
 char Tmp[]="";
```

here, `Tmp` is **not** an dynamic array, it's an array with *exactly* one element (initialized via the initializer). When you use this as destination for `strcpy()`, you're overrunning the buffer. Basically, your code tries to access out of bound memory, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.24.2.3, *`strcpy()`*, *emphasis mine*

> The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` **(including the terminating null
>   character)** into the array pointed to by `s1`. [...]

and then, for "String function conventions", §7.24.1,

> [....] If an array is accessed beyond the end of an object, the behavior is undefined.

**Solution**: You need to ensure that `Tmp` has enough memory to hold the content to be copied into it, including the null terminator.

That said, for a hosted environment, `int main()` should at least be `int main(void)` to be conforming to the standard.